# How do we get recording logs in jmeter if we are recording a script via HTTPS Proxy server?

Tags: jmeter-5.0

Just like in Loadrunner where we get recording logs to help us with what values were returned by server during recording, is there a way to do the same in jmeter?

I initially though it would be working by adding debug post processor in HTTPS recording server but that is not allowed.

Comment: For e.g., I am recording a step on UI and when samples are generated for this step, is there a way to capture server response for this sampler?

Answer (score 0):

Responses from the server can be captured by adding *View Results Tree* *Listener* under the *HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder*. This way all the responses will be logged in the Listener and can be viewed later, to compare with replay response or to correlate dynamic values. Make sure to save the responses by providing *File location* in *Filename* field of *View Results Tree* to use it for later time.